# How to manage a multitable database?

Tags: android, database, cursor, uri

I just got done reviewing the Notepad tutorial and looking at how they do their database. If you wanted to expand it to a multi-table database, would you just add a new provider class that did anything possibly needed for that table?

Second If you don't mind answering a second slightly related question, What is a URI and how do I use them with android? I searched around and only came back with "Universal Resource Identifier".

Thank
~Aedon

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The idea of a Provider is that it deals with a type of public resource.  So you have a Contact provider or a Note provider.  The provider isn't tied to the database in any way.  A Note provider might be accessing dozens of tables behind the provider interface.

You can think of the provider interface as being being a public API to your resources.  Its available to all applications on the phone as a mechanism for sharing a common resource.  The method of implementing that API is an implementation detail for the provider itself.  The provider might not use a database at all (perhaps it uses a web service only) or it might use a multitable/multidatabase design.

A URI is a Universal Resource Indicator.  The Cliff's notes of it are this: The uri has a scheme and a locator.  In android, the scheme, the portion of the uri before the :, is used to determine what you intended for the uri to do.  A URI like sms://5555555551 is registered to be requesting a text to be sent 555-555-5551.  The 555-555-5551 is referred to as the 'data'.

There is much more to read and understand [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/IntentFilter.html).  Suffice to say, in Android, URI's are frequently used to loosely couple activities together.  For instance, in my previous example, I care only that an sms is sent, not how it is sent.  This allows many apps to register to be able to send sms messages, apps better, perhaps, then the ones that Android has built into the platform.

Comment: I realize that this doesn't not address how you would expand the example to use multiple database tables, but it seemed, based on the question, that this answer might be some necessary explanation.  If you have additional questions about using multiple tables or databases, i can try to answer those too.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed reply. So then what would the best way to tackle a 5 table database?

Comment: It really depends what it is you are trying to serve.  Is it a reservation app where all 5 tables support making reservations AND you want other apps to be able to hook into your reservation data store?  If so, a single content provider would be great.  Is each database its own standalone resource that you want to expose to the world?  I can't come up with an example for 5, but the question you should ask is 'what is/are the resource(s) i hope to expose to the world with my content provider?'  Then design a content provider to support that resource.  Does that make sense?

Comment: Yes thank you. With your help and the further research I have done, It seems to all come together now. Thanks again.